# bower install not generate library in my project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular.module
('newApp', [ 'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages'
  ])

    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'main'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
})();
```

i am trying to install bower using command "bower install".
It gives nothing and even no error is coming.

Comment: Have you added angular library ?

Comment: Post your complete code and html view

Comment: create a demo (fiddle/plunker) and we can help you better.. :)

Comment: you probably forgot to put the right order for the scripts you try to load there.

Comment: it works fine if you included scripts with perfect order.

Comment: actually i am trying to install bower using this command "bower install" it will not generates angular library in my project even no error is coming .

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the global `angular` in `IIFE` if you added angular in html by `script` tag

```
(function (angular) {

  'use strict';

  angular.module
('newApp', [ 'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages'
  ])

    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'main'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
})(angular);
```

Comment: actually i am trying to install bower using this command "bower install" it will not generates angular library in my project even no error is coming.